# How to create stacked bar/column charts in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I know that conventional bar charts (with the bars adjacent to each other) based on feature attributes can be plotted in QGIS. But can you please tell me if there's any way to plot the bars in the form of stacks, as in stacked bar/column charts, in QGIS? I tried to find an example in the QGIS manual and on the internet but wasn't able to get any information about it.

Comment: I am also looking for an answer to this, I can create bar charts but really I would like to see the objects stacked not parallel to eachother.